# How to get this chest in Noria mines?

Tags: evoland

There are a few chests in Noria Mines that I can see but can't get. One of them is on the picture:

[image: Chest]

This is straight east from the save point. Any idea how get to these? This one in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer here:

This particular chest is at 8:12. Turns out that you are supposed to return for this one (and a couple of others) once you get bombs. Who would have thought?

Comment: Anyone that played Zelda would have thought :)